# Spring boot TemplateInputException

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am testing Spring boot with a simple project and I have a TemplateInputException on a post method.

Here is my Controller :

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

import com.astrea.annuaire.domain.User;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/annuaire")
public class AnnuaireController {

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String main(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("user", new User());
        return "connection";
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String connection(@ModelAttribute User user, Model model) {
        System.out.println("Connection attempted by " + user.toString());
        return null;
    }

}
```

Here is my User class :

```
public class User {

    private String name;

    private String password;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

}
```

Here is my connection.html file :

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head> 
    <title>Connexion</title> 
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</head>
<body>
    <form action="#" th:action="@{/annuaire}" th:object="${user}" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="pseudo" th:field="*{name}" placeholder="Nom d'utilisateur" />
        <input type="password" name="pwd" th:field="*{password}" placeholder="Mot de passe" />
        <input type="submit" name="valider" value="Se connecter"/>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my pom :

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.1.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

The GET method (named main) works successfully, but when I submit the form, I've got this error :

```
org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Error resolving template "annuaire", template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers
```

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you return `null`, Spring interprets that as "figure out the view name for me" and converts the request URL into a view. Thereby `POST /annuaire` turns into "annuaire" and Spring tries to render that template.

So you need to do something different, and there are a few options:

1. Add an `HttpServletResponse` parameter to your POST handler. Spring will infer that you handled the response yourself and not try to render a view.
2. Return a `ResponseEntity<?>` to explicitly handle the response.
3. Write a template for the POST handler and return its name.
4. Redirect by returning `"redirect:<redirect-url>"`.

The last one probably makes the most sense; `"redirect:/annuaire"` will send the browser back to your form.

Comment: Thank you Steve, it works well with a returned value ! As my syso wasn't printed, I though the problem was before entering the post method but apparently the returned value is preprocessed by Spring which misled me.